# Represent webcam video as stream of pixel arrays in Python

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-streaming

I'm wondering if there is a way to analyse each frame of my webcam video per second as an array of pixels. For example:

So if my resolution of my webcam was 3 x 3 (it's not) the I would get a constantly refreshing list of this form(or close).

```
pixel_list = [[(R, G, B), (R, G, B)], [(R, G, B), (R, G, B)], [(R, G, B), (R, G, B)]}
```

Thanks!

A lot of my googling has pushed me in the direction of opencv, but i'm not sure 'how' exactly to get what i need done.

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go!

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
while True:
    print(cap.read())
```

The new OpenCV API (module `cv2`) uses NumPy arrays for images.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Video4Linux to open your webcam, and to retrieve frames. Once youget the frames, you have pixel data. Here is a link to the Python binding for v4l:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/v4l2

Depending on what you need to do on the frames (which processing ?), opencv may be a good
choice but for basic or even more advanced video data analysis, scipy is very good. There
are also other image processing toolkits for Python.